# On target reached in Smooth scroller in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, smooth-scrolling

[Here is how my app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62d5e.jpg)

I have a horizontal suppressed recyclerview and once the user clicks an answer it smoothscrolls to the next one
, tho I wanted to prevent clicks while the smooth scrolling is still going

I used a handler and had many try and error until I got it to work on phones,
however, it isn't practical and doesn't work the same for every phone

```
     public  void setSmoothScroller(final float speed){
    smoothScroller  = new LinearSmoothScroller(getApplicationContext()) {
      
        private  final float SPEED = speed;
        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
      
            return SPEED / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }
    };
}
```

it could be complicated trying to explain but all i need is instead of using handlers to enable touching again , is there a way to make it automatically perform a function on reaching the specific position

```
          @Override
public void onAnswered(final int position) {

   if (answered < bank){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollingState = true;
                recyclerView.suppressLayout(true);
                setSmoothScroller(300f);
                smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position + 1);
                layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
            }
        }, 1000);
        
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                enableTouch();
            }
        }, 3150);

    }
}
```

Comment: please upload your related code, how you implement smooth scroll

Comment: i edited it just now , take a look please , i am sorry i couldn't provide more code but it is because it really is a big project

Comment: use `Smoothscrolltoposition` for smooth scroll